# Laravel NumberFormatter со склонениями

Tags: php, laravel, composer, package

Всем привет

Подскажите, есть ли на Github или в движке самого Laravel возможность склонять цифры?

Что имею ввиду

Есть предложение

> "в течение пяти"

фраза добавлена в локализации в виде шаблона "в течение :count"

из базы достаю цифровое значение и переделываю его в слово в зависимости от локализации

```
$lessons_count_word = new \NumberFormatter($locale, \NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
$lessons_count_word = $lessons_count_word->format($count);
```

но такая реализация генерирует не корректные фразы

"в течение **один**"

"в течение **два**"

"в течение **три**"
и тд
а нужно

"в течение **одного**"

"в течение **двух**"

"в течение **трех**"
и тд

При этом чтоб локализация работала, потому что не на всех языках есть склонения

Есть ли способ сделать это без создания своих функций со всеми языками локализаций для всех цифр?

Comment: [https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/localization#pluralization](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/localization#pluralization) таки есть с коробки данный инструмент, мультиязычная плюрализация присутствует безо всяких пакетов

Comment: @InDevX там речь идет про множественные формы слов в зависимости от числа, а тут вопрос про склонение самих числительных. То есть там "1 яблок**О**" или "2 яблок**а**" а тут про "**одно** яблоко" и "**двадцати трех** яблок"

Comment: Ужас какой) Значит соболезную.

Comment: Для этого можно взять любую доступную библиотеку ([PEAR](https://github.com/pear/Numbers_Words/blob/master/Numbers/Words/Locale/ru.php) или любой другой [аналог](https://snipp.ru/php/amount-words)), конвертирующую число в текст, и скорректировать текстовое название из "три" в "трёх", "два" в "двух" и т.д.